# Winforms custom control with designer testing in VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I created a custom control, and a custom designer for the control in separate projects.
The control project is targeting .Net 4.0 Client Profile, and designer - Full Profile, as I need reference to System.Design.

I created third project for testing, it is targeting .Net 4.0 Client Profile.

I sign both assemblies and install both in GAC after each build.

But, even after the control is rebuilt, VS still shows old version in the control tool bar until VS is restarted.

How can I modify the control and designer and test them without restarting the VS?

Comment: Generally speaking, what you see is by design. If I were you, I might use Visual Studio 2012 as IDE for coding, and VS2010 as the target.

Comment: I don't understand how this can help.  The control is just one small component of a big solution, and I want to use the component on multiple forms and controls. Now when I rebuild the solution, I can't edit the edit the component, and drop controls into it.  This is really annoying, because I need to rebuild everything very often.